# \newcommand inside a \newcommand: variable already defined

Tags: macros

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\ARROW}[2]{
  \ifstrequal{#2}{left}{
    \newcommand{\coef}{-1}
  }{}
  \ifstrequal{#2}{right}{
    \newcommand{\coef}{1}
  }{};
  \coordinate(a) at (#1);
  \coordinate(b) at ($(a) + (\coef*2cm, 0)$);
  \draw[->](a) -- (b);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \ARROW{1, 0}{right};
  \ARROW{2, 1}{left};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When invoking the second time the `\newcommand` `\ARROW` (`\ARROW{2, 1}{left};`) the code complains that `\coef` is already designed.

How to optimise the code to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Add \newcommand\coef{} outside the definition and use \renewcommand or \def inside.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I checked. You can supply this an answer.

Comment: You can set `\newcommand{\ARROW}[2]{{...}}`. Then `\coef` will be local inside `\ARROW`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using keys?

```
\documentclass[border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  /viesturs/right/.code=\def\ARROWCOEFF{+},
  /viesturs/left/.code=\def\ARROWCOEFF{-},
}

\newcommand{\ARROW}[2]{%
  \tikzset{/viesturs/#2}
  \coordinate(a) at (#1);
  \coordinate(b) at ($(a) + (\ARROWCOEFF 2cm, 0)$);
  \draw[->](a) -- (b);
}
\providecommand{\ARROWCOEFF}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \ARROW{1, 0}{right};
  \ARROW{2, 1}{left};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]